# Python 3 Dictionary sorted with wrong output

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I am currently doing an Assignment; however, I got some interesting output which confused me so much.

I am trying to sort the following dictionary:

```
result = {'A1': '9', 'A2': '14', 'A3': '16', 'A4': '0', 'B1': '53', 'B2': '267', 'B3': '75', 'B4': '22', 'C1': '19', 'C2': '407', 'C3': '171', 'C4': '56', 'C5': '10', 'D3': '47', 'D4': '34', 'D5': '10'}
```

My sorting code with Python 3 is the following : (only sorted by value)

```
sortedList = [v for v in sorted(result.values())]
```

The output is :

```
['0', '10', '10', '14', '16', '171', '19', '22', '267', '34', '407', '47', '53', '56', '75', '9']
```

which is not fully sorted. The output is quite strange.

Why it is happened like this?
I have used another dict to test like this:

```
testD = {'A':'5','B': '9','c': '8','d': '6'}
```

the output is right :

```
['5', '6', '8', '9']
```

Is there something wrong with my **result** **dictionary** or is there something I am missing?

Comment: They are strings, you are doing lexical sorting... if you need `int` ordering but keep them as strings you can use the `key` arg to `sorted()`... `sorted(result.values(), key=int)`

Answer (score 0):

Strings will be ordered with a lexical sort. To sort your data numerically, convert the values into integers first.

Answer (score 0):

As the value of dictionary are string so there is **lexical sorting** based on ascii values.

As evident, you need the values to be sorted according to their integer values.

```
result = {'A1': '9', 'A2': '14', 'A3': '16', 'A4': '0', 'B1': '53', 'B2': '267', 'B3': '75', 'B4': '22', 'C1': '19', 'C2': '407', 'C3': '171', 'C4': '56', 'C5': '10', 'D3': '47', 'D4': '34', 'D5': '10'}
```

As mentioned in the comments by @AChampion, you can pass the sort value type by using `key` something like this :

```
sortedList = sorted(result.values(), key = int)
print(sortedList)
```

Or you can do something like this :

```
result_ints = dict((k,int(v)) for k,v in result.items())
sortedList = [str(v) for v in sorted(result_ints.values())]
print(sortedList)
```

Both of the above code snippets will result in :

```
['0', '9', '10', '10', '14', '16', '19', '22', '34', '47', '53', '56', '75', '171', '267', '407']
```

Comment: You really don't need to do all this converting, `sorted(results.values(), key=int)` would do the same thing in one step.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are compared one character at a time, so `'30' < '4'` because `'3' < '4'`. You need to use a `key` parameter to get the comparison based on the numeric value, not the string characters.

Also, it's redundant to use a list comprehension on something that already returns a list.

```
sortedList = sorted(result.values(), key=int)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
result = [{'A1': '9', 'A2': '14', 'A3': '16', 'A4': '0', 'B1': '53', 'B2': '267', 'B3': '75', 'B4': '22', 'C1': '19', 'C2': '407', 'C3': '171', 'C4': '56', 'C5': '10', 'D3': '47', 'D4': '34', 'D5': '10'}]

lst=[] 

for item in result:
    for key in item.keys():
        lst.append(int(item.get(key)))        

sortedList = [v for v in sorted(lst)]
print(sortedList)
```

> Output: [0, 9, 10, 10, 14, 16, 19, 22, 34, 47, 53, 56, 75, 171, 267,
>   407]